# VBA copy non-blank cells to a master workbook

Tags: vba

I'm a very beginner at vba. I'm trying to write a macro that helps me to loop through all workbooks in a folder going through each cell of that workbook. If the cell is empty then paste it onto the cell of a master workbook with the same position as the original one (these workbooks share the same format). this is what I have and I know that it's wrong. Please help me out. Really appreciate your advice. Thanks.

```
Sub copycat()

Dim x As Range
Set x = ActiveCell

For Each Cell In 
    Workbooks("work2.xlsm").Worksheets("sheet1").Range("a1:j10")

    If IsEmpty(Cell.Value) = False Then

        Workbooks("work2.xlsm").Worksheets("sheet1").Range("x").Copy 
        Workbooks("work2.xlsm").Worksheets("sheet1").Range("x")

    End If

Next Cell


End Sub
```

Comment: Are you trying to copy the Empty Cells (according to your post), or none-empty cells (according to the code you attached). Also, what is the name of the `Workbook` you want to paste it to ?

Comment: Hi Michal,the idea is that I have a folder of 5 workbooks with the same format but having different ranges filled in ( collected from different people,each person filter to their range and filled in). now I need to consolidate all of the filled-in data into a master workbook called master workbook instead of having to manually copy and paste. that's why I need to copy cells from the collected workbook and paste it onto the exact same cell position in the "master workbook"

Answer (score 0):

The code below will copy all the none-empty cells in your Range.

You have not specified the destination `Workbook` you want to paste these values.

```
Sub copycat()

Dim Cell As Range

For Each Cell In Workbooks("work2.xlsm").Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1:J10")
    If Trim(Cell.Value) <> "" Then ' if cell is not empty
        Cell.Copy ' <-- copy the cell

        ' not sure where you want to paste it ??

    End If
Next Cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Shai,the idea is that I have a folder of 5 workbooks with the same format.

Comment: but have different ranges filled in ( collected from different people,each person filter to their range and filled in). now I need to consolidate all of the filled-in data into a master workbook called master workbook instead of having to manually copy and paste. that's why I need to copy cells from the collected workbook and paste it onto the exact same cell position in the master workbook.